# How can I check If a message exists in the guild? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I know there is a way to check if a message exists or not  by `<channel>.messages.fetch(id)`.

But I need to check if the message exists in the **entire guild** (All Channels in a guild) . Something like `<guild>.messages.fetch(id)`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Nope. Not unless you iterate through every channel in a guild and run that function (which will very quickly become API spam)

Comment: @Lioness100 so there isnt a way to check if a simple message exists?